# How to calculate a date field in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I'm using a date field as a conditional element. If cell A1 which is date field is empty (no date has been entered yet), then leave the cell A2 blank. If there is a date entered into A1, run a calculation (which I already have).

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? And what have you already tried?

Comment: I need an IF statement that looks at a cell (that's formatted as a date field) and if that cell is empty, return " ". If that cell has a date, return a formula. I have the formula working. But because the cell is formatted as a date field, a conditional such as >1 doesn't seem to work. What would a conditional be for seeing if the cell actually had a date or if it was blank. Any of this make sense? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an `IsEmpty()` function in Numbers for this, so the formula probably will look something like

```
=if(IsEmpty(CELL-REFERENCE),"",YOUR-FORMULA)
```

Comment: Glad that worked for you, @SteelNewt  Please mark the answer as accepted for the benefit of others who may have a similar problem.  Cheers!